# render JSON formatted response when accessing undefined routes in Rails API service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, error-handling, routes, rails-api

Here is the situation:

If a user try to access my rails-api service with an undefined route, rails would catch an exception and render an html with `Routing Error:` to the browser.

But what i want my rails-api service to perform is that it can catch any errors like this and return a `json-formatted` error info to the request source, like below:

```
# if i visit a route which is undefined in my config/routes.rb like this:

HTTP.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/route/of/undefined')

# what i want it to render to the page is:

{status: 404, err_msg: 'route of undefined, please check again.'}
```

Before i take my action, i find that Rails matches a request with a route happens before it initializes a controller, thus if i add `rescue_from` to my `ApplicationController`,  ApplicationController has no chance to rescue the exception.

also, i added line below to my project:

```
# config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes

# config/environments/development.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

what next should I do? i searched a lot but could not find an answer to solve this problem. especially in an `rails api service`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render same response for all undefined routes, you can do something like below,

```
match '*path', to: "error_controller#handle_root_not_found", via: [:get, :post]
```

add this line at the end of route.rb.
After that generate `error_controller` and define `handle_root_not_found` method there which will render your custom response.

```
def handle_root_not_found
   render json: { message: "route not found"}, status: 404
end
```

So what will happen in this scenario is when you request a particular route, it will scan route file from top to bottom manner.
If that route will be found then it will redirect you to that.
If route is not found untill `match '*path'` line then this line will redirect it to `handle_root_not_found` method which will render our custom response.